# Curl Response in new line on terminal

Tags: python, bash, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have AWS Lambda function , whom for example returns "hello World" , Then I execute my code:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://xxxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/statusok/xxxxxx -d @keyValue.json
```

I get response in terminal:

```
"Hello World!"andrejka@root:~/Desktop/Darbas/KeyValue$
```

The question is how i can change my code or execution script to get response in new line, like :

```
"Hello World!"
andrejka@root:~/Desktop/Darbas/KeyValue$
```

I already try /n but nothing. Please suggest!

Comment: just add -w "\n" to your curl command

Comment: Thanks!!! -w "\n" is works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest solution would be simply executing an `echo` statement after your `curl`-call like:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -X POST https://xxxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/statusok/xxxxxx \
     -d @keyValue.json; echo
```

Comment: Thanks!!! -w "\n" is works!